# What does 'module' refer to in Java?

Tags: java, definition

I'm taking a data structures class right now, and we have a programming assignment. One of the guidelines is to keep code 'modular,' about a page per module. We never used this term in my programming class, and I can't really tell if 'module' in this case refers to class, method, or some other concept. Is the concept of a module in Java established, and if so, what does it refer to? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Java does not currently have a formal concept of "module"; Project Jigsaw will add them in Java 9.

Comment: I think in this context it means some classes which belong to together e.g. when you have some classes which are responsible for persisting objects.

Comment: I think your question would be better if it was "what does modular mean", it will make it language semi-agnostic too

Comment: Thanks all. niceman, my question has been marked as duplicate, but I asked this one separately because in that response the comments were that it depended on language! :-)